# How to translate this E.R diagram to table?

Tags: sql, erd

Hello I need help translating this E.R diagram to table

Do I create a table for each entity and relationship ?

[Partial/total participation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wh2sy.png)

Comment: Welcome to the community, but your relationships are so vague, it's not practical.  Can you give better context of what you are trying to do / create / purpose.  Even if it is describing what you are trying to build, only then might you get better response vs immediate close on the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
  Create Table E ( Id VARCHAR(10) PRIMARY KEY)
  CREATE TABLE R(ID VARCHAR(10) FOREIGN KEY 
 REFERENCES E(Id)) , Value VARCHAR(10))

    INSERT INTO E VALUES("R1");
    INSERT INTO E VALUES("R2");
   INSERT INTO R VALUES("R1",A1);
    INSERT INTO R VALUES("R2",A2);
```

> Meaning each entity `E` is an `ID` and `Id` has a Value (1-1) meaning for each id one value but E has many ids (0-n). But you should agree that the relationships are impractical and are of no use.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, this means that entities `E1` and `E2` have one-to-many relation with the entity `E`. In a way, you could define a table for each entity `E`, `E1` and `E2` and define the foreign keys of `E1` and `E2` in the `E` table.

Comment: yeah thats what the unclear (0-n) ?? called as per the OP's query having all the entities E1,E2,..En as we refer as `Is a Relationship` then thereafter `has a ` R1 or becomes R1 with one to one has a Value as A1 likewise. simply limbo relationship i could say via unclear ER